# Why cant i do file write in php?

Tags: php, sockets, fwrite

Hi i have a client connecting to a socket server in php.

I want to empty a particular file after connecting to the server, however, the codes is not giving me any error but it is not writing to the file?

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);

//parameters to connect to server
$ip = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "1245";
$data = "";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$result = socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);

$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, ""); 

while (true)
{
        $data = "some value here"

        socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

        $line =@socket_read($socket,2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if($line != "")
        {
                echo $line."\n";
        }   

}
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: for a start your not ending the string `$data = "some value here"
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an absolute path `$myFile = "/tmp/test.txt";` to make sure I knew where the file was to be written. Right now with just text.txt it could be written in a variety of places but most likely where the web servers binary is located.

If you'd rather not use an absolute path you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php
and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php to control the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the file is writable before trying to open it:

```
if(is_writable($myFile)) {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
} else {
  die('unable to write to '.$myFile);
}
```